# What should the behavior of Disabled Link/Button be?

Tags: interaction-design, buttons, popup, tooltips, context-sensitive-help

What is the best practice for designing disabled states? In general disabled states cannot be interacted with. 
Any opinions on presenting a tooltip/pop-up on hover or click when the user interacts with a disabled/greyed out link or button.

Answer (score 2):

**Adding a Tooltip to tell users why a button is disabled is a good way to reduce frustration!**

Disabling a button could be frustrating and confusing to users in many cases, as yes users usually **cannot interact** with a disabled button/object. Adding a Tooltip that guides users on the reason an object is disabled is one way of interaction that would **reduce users' frustration.**

Take this example: Add Course button is disabled till all mandatory fields are filled out. When the button is hovered, a Tooltip will display to explain why the button is still disabled.

-*Note: When all mandatory fields are filled out, the Tooltip content could be changed to explain the button functionality, or simply do not display it if it is not needed anymore.*

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx4VN1.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Update: I just found this [answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/922/hover-over-a-disabled-item-to-know-why-its-disabled-what-do-you-think?rq=1) to support the idea.

Comment: What about a scenario for Mobile Devices?
Would it be better to show a text message as label above the button?

Comment: @HarishRaghuraman Maybe if you add a little help icon, when pushed, it displays info explaining why the button is disabled. The icon only stays displayed while the button is disabled.

Comment: @HarishRaghuraman check [This](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/96560/should-a-button-be-disabled-under-offline-situation-or-clickable-with-a-notifica/125588#125588) very similar answer to a case for Mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I can always tell a disabled state from two things:

1. The element is 'greyed-out' in some fashion, to distinguish it from other, active elements around it. (Which you've mentioned)
2. The 'pointer' cursor does not show when hovering over the element.

The [Material design guidelines](https://material.io/design/interaction/states.html#disabled) have some good information regarding disabled states, but I'd start with *completely* disabling interaction on the button - clicking it does nothing, hovering it does nothing, etc.

I'd also advise against a pop-up on hover or click, as it will remove the user from the current experience in a very jarring fashion; pop-ups should generally be used for immediate, high priority feedback.